# How to make sure that I always get project root directory

Tags: java, groovy, filepath

I've got the following project structure:

[image]

There are cases that I need to read the `Config.groovy` file. To get the file path I say

```
String localDir = System.getProperty("user.dir")
String configPath= localDir + File.separator + "config" + File.separator + "Config.groovy";
```

But there's a problem here. If I call it from inside the `main` class I get

```
D:\Programs\CheckFraudAlarms
```

and if I call it from inside the `utils.UtilGroovies` class, I get

```
D:\Programs\CheckFraudAlarms\src
```

which results in invalid path for the Config.groovy file. How can I make sure that I always get the project root folder, no matter where I call the `System.getProperty` method?

Comment: have you tried getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("/config/Config.groovy") ?

Answer (score 2):

One way could be to set the **absolute path** of your config directory as value of a `System` property for example `conf.dir`, you will then need to set it in your launch command with `"-Dconf.dir=c:\path\to\config\"`. You could also use `user.dir` as System property.

---

Another way could be to add the `config` directory to the **classpath** of your application, to be able to get it from the context `ClassLoader` as next:

```
String configPath = new File(
    Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("Config.groovy").toURI()
).getAbsolutePath();
```